# Why is this code not working for leetcode #1664?

Tags: python

The following code:

```
class Solution:   
    def waysToMakeFair(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        def sumOfIndexes(l1):
            oddVal = 0
            evenVal = 0
            for i in range(1,len(l1),2):
                oddVal += nums[i]
                evenVal += nums[i-1]
            return [oddVal,evenVal]
        # Computes Sum of Odd and Even Indexes of a List.
        numRemoval = 0
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            x = nums[i]
            del nums[i]
            soiList = sumOfIndexes(nums)
            oddVal = soiList[0]
            evenVal = soiList[1]
            if oddVal == evenVal:
                numRemoval += 1
            nums.insert(i,x)
            return numRemoval
```

seems to not work for leetcode #1664. Does anyone know why?

It's supposed to return the number of possible indexes you can remove while the odd index values and even index values add up to the same value. When the input value is [2,1,6,4] the code outputs 0. Does anyone know why it does this?

Comment: We're not going to look up whatever "leetcode #1664" is. Please include all relevant information _here_, as part of your question.

Comment: What happened when you set breakpoints and executed the code step by step, inspecting variables?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: In your `sumOfIndexes` function, you calculate the sums of the original `nums` list instead of the `l1` list passed as parameter! By the way, `sum(l1[::2])` and `sum(l1[1::2])` would remove the need for a loop. Plus, you should remove only 1 element of a COPY of the original nums each time.

Comment: Ok, looking a bit more at your code: though my previous comment and Joerie's ones are valid, the main problem is the way you calculate oddVal and evenVal: when nums is of even length, the list passed to SumOfIndexes is of odd length; then the way your loop is constructed, the last element is not counted in the total. Add `print(nums, soiList)` after calling it and you'll see...

Comment: After you have fixed these issues, you'll find your algorithm is not efficient and will still not pass the tests. You need a different algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The two bugs have already been mentioned (misplaced `return` and not summing the final element when the list's size is odd). Correcting these issues will still mean your algorithm has a quadratic time complexity. If the tests are good enough, your algorithm may not pass them. You then need a better algorithm.

This can be solved with linear time complexity. The idea is that you precalculate partial sums (with steps of 2) in both directions. That way you can know what the odd/even sums will be after removing a value, without having to iterate the whole list again.

Here is some code that takes that approach:

```
class Solution:
    def waysToMakeFair(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        def getsums(nums):
            sums = [0, 0]
            for val in nums:
                sums.append(sums[-2] + val)
            return sums

        leftsums = getsums(nums)
        rightsums = getsums(nums[::-1])[::-1]

        return sum(
            leftsums[i+1] + rightsums[i+2] == leftsums[i] + rightsums[i+1]
            for i in range(len(nums))
        )
```

This can probably be done in a more elegant way, but it does the job.

Comment: Nice, after seeing your solution yesterday evening I though that a buffer of [0, 0] would remove the need to check for (literally) edge cases. And during my nighttime you implemented it :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible errors:

1. You don't take into account that when you remove an element these indices change.
2. The return statement is incorrectly indented.

I think you want something like this

```py
class Solution:
    def waysToMakeFair(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        def sumOfIndexes(l1):
            # your implementation

        numRemoval = 0
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            x = nums[i]
            del nums[i]
            soiList = sumOfIndexes(nums)
            oddVal = soiList[0]
            evenVal = soiList[1]
            if oddVal == evenVal:
                numRemoval += 1
            nums.insert(i, x)

        return numRemoval
```

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 main problems in your code.

- As Joerie pointed out, the `return` was badly indented.
- The `for i in range(1,len(l1),2):` loop would miss the last element of l1 if l1 was of odd length.

The rest of the code (removing 1 element of nums then putting it back) was actually correct, contrary to what I stated in my comment.

Here's some corrected code:

```
class Solution:   
    def waysToMakeFair(self, nums: list[int]) -> int:
        def IsFair(l1):
            return sum(l1[::2]) == sum(l1[1::2])
        numRemoval = 0
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            x = nums[i]
            del nums[i]
            numRemoval += IsFair(nums)
            nums.insert(i,x)
        return numRemoval
```

Test:

```
Solution().waysToMakeFair([2, 1, 6, 4])
1
```